# Why is there an option to flag deleted answers?

Tags: support

When an answer is deleted (displayed with red background for those of use that can see deleted posts), why do I still have the option to `flag` it?

If this is not a mistake, then what is an example scenario where I would want to flag a deleted post? My understanding was the flagging was for answers that I feel should be removed (either by the user or by a moderator), but if they have already been deleted then why would I need to flag?

In fact, why are the `share` and `edit` links there too?

If anyone needs a quick reference to a deleted answer, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955114/838807)

Comment: Edit can be useful - some questions gets undeleted. Flag *might* be useful, if post is evil beyond measures, ie underage porn, and should be burnt and salted so no one ever sees what was there (except police, on backups). Share is mystery for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see a number of good use cases for flagging:

- You believe the post should be undeleted.
- There is something in there that needs to be purged entirely (like a secret password, for example) and want to alert a moderator to this. Even if the moderator can't deal with this directly, they should be able to escalate it appropriately if you don't know how.
- You believe the post's author is up to something suspicious, and you want to explain the situation to a moderator.

Similarly, editing is fine. Perhaps someone sees a way to fix a deleted answer before then proceeding to flag for undeletion.

The share button just gives the permalink to the post, which might be useful to share with other 10k users (for example, to post the link in a meta post).

Comment: 10k+ users can see deleted questions - so share works for them.

Comment: I guess the share is there so I can link an example in this question

Comment: @juergend, good point. I updated my answer to show the use case for sharing.

Comment: FYI: Although all the answers make good points, I have accepted this one as it is more detailed and also goes on to give examples of the `edit` and `share` features too

Answer (score 2):

An example scenario I can think of is: if a mod deletes your answer, which you disagree with, you could flag it, giving your reasons as to why you think it should be undeleted.

Comment: Ahh, so the flag could be to request an "undelete". This could be applicable regardless of if it is my answer or not

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the answer might need to be deleted entirely, for example, if it contains offensive or private material. You wouldn't even want 10K+ users to see it.

You can flag the answer to ask a Stack Exchange staff member to permanently delete the post or edit out the offensive content.

Comment: Moderators cannot permanently delete posts.

Comment: @Yannis but have better chance to contact dev teams about that.

Comment: @Yannis I thought mods could do that too. Only staff members then? I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I was wondering if this was possible, yet @Yannis seems to disagree

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, only SE employees. They'd probably nuke revisions that have private information in them, but... I don't think anyone would care enough to nuke offensive posts, however offensive those might be. If the post is evil beyond measures, just an edit that would make its evilness less obvious, would be enough.

Comment: Moderators can't but the dev team can completely kill something and prevent it from being seen.

Answer (score 1):

Another case:

You got question banned for your bad questions. Some of them got deleted (or you deleted them). You can improve them and flag for undeletion to get a few upvotes and get over the ban.

Comment: I didn't even know you could get banned from asking questions...